# listen to event with node-opcua

Tags: node.js, opc-ua, node-opcua

I am trying to listen to an event called 'EventPretreatDone'.

[Event Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1uIy.png)

Using the example to minitor an Event found in the node-opcua library i can't get any results.

```
  async createSubscription() {
    const session = await this.opcClient.createSession();
    const subscription = ClientSubscription.create(session, {
      requestedPublishingInterval: 1000,
      requestedLifetimeCount: 100,
      requestedMaxKeepAliveCount: 10,
      maxNotificationsPerPublish: 100,
      publishingEnabled: true,
      priority: 10,
    });
    const filter = new EventFilter({
      selectClauses: [
        { browsePath: [{ name: 'ActiveState' }, { name: 'id' }] },
        { browsePath: [{ name: 'ConditionName' }] },
      ],
    });

    subscription.monitor(
      // itemToMonitor:
      {
        nodeId: 'ns=1;s=EventPretreatDone',
        attributeId: AttributeIds.EventNotifier,
        indexRange: null,
        dataEncoding: { namespaceIndex: 0, name: null },
      },
      // requestedParameters:
      {
        samplingInterval: 3000,

        filter: filter,

        queueSize: 1000,
        discardOldest: true,
      },
      TimestampsToReturn.Neither,
    );
  }
```

There is a Pyhton script provided in the machines (server) documentation that shows it is possible to listen to this specific event.

```
import asyncio

import logging

import json


from asyncua import Client, ua



logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


logging.getLogger("asyncua").setLevel(logging.ERROR)


async def print_event(event):

    data = json.loads(event.Message.Text)

    logger.debug(event.EventType)

    logger.debug(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))



class EventListener:

    

    def __init__(self, url):

        self._URL = url


    async def event_notification(self, event):

        async def debug_print(event):

            logger.debug(event)


        fun = {

            ua.StringNodeId('EventPretreatDone', 1): print_event,
         
        }.get(event.EventType, debug_print)


        await fun(event)



    async def process_opcua(self):

        while True:

            try:

                logger.info("Trying to connect...")

                async with Client(url=self._URL) as client:

                    logger.info("Connected")

                    

                    logger.info("Subscribing events")

                    sub = await client.create_subscription(10, self)

                    handle = await sub.subscribe_events(queuesize=10)

                    

                    while True:

                        await asyncio.gather(

                            asyncio.sleep(1.0)

                        )

                        

                        

            except Exception as ex:

                logger.warning(ex)

                await asyncio.sleep(0.5)



async def main():

    listener = EventListener("opc.tcp://10.0.6.107:4840")

    await asyncio.gather(

        listener.process_opcua()

    )



if __name__ == "__main__":

    asyncio.run(main())
```

I would like to avoid a mix of python and javascript in my service.